# Socket Hang Up error with no common symptoms

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, request

I'm running a small HTTP server on an RPI3B. It logs every request made, so in Postman, I can make a request to the server and it is received, logged and returns the correct value. However, using this function:

```
function get(action, path, content) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let body = "";
        let req = http.request({
            host: "10.0.0.12",
            method: content ? "post" : "get",
            path: `${action}?path=${path}`,
            headers: {
                token
            }
        }, res => {
            res.on('data', data => {
                body += data;
            })
            res.on("end", e => {
                resolve(body.toString());
            })
        });
        req.end(content);
        req.on("error", e => {
            reject(e);
        })
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

```
(node:24956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:313:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:416:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:24956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an asyn
c function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24956) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not
 handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have looked at common symptoms of this error and noted that I receive the error immediately after the request is sent (as opposed to when the request times out). I also noted that I have the `req.end()` method called to ensure the request is ended, but the result remains the same.

Any insight as to how this might be caused and how it might be resolvable would be greatly appreciated.

**Note** Both sides are written in Node.JS

Comment: It looks like no end event is fired. Try add resolve as a callback in end function `req.end(content);` BTW, callback for 'end' even doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: I'm aware that the `end` event doesn't take any arguments, I simply prefer not having parens on arrow functions, It's just a preference.

Comment: changing `req.end(content)` to req.end(resolve)` has fixed the issue. I simply added `req.write(content)` before `req.end(resolve)`